# Parametrization pion fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, sigma-models

The exercise 5.8 of the book "Gauge theory of elementary particle physics - Problems and Solutions" by Ta-Pei Cheng and Ling-Fong Li has a point:

Let us consider an isospin one pion field $\mathbf{\pi}=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$ and an isospin zero scalar field $\sigma$. Let us collect them in a $2\times 2$ matrix to represent the spin $0$ fields collectively

\begin{equation}
\Sigma=\sigma+i\mathbf{\tau}\cdot \mathbf{\pi}
\end{equation}

where $\tau^a$ are the Pauli matrices. A non-linear $\sigma$-model is obtained by imposing the constraint of

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2+\mathbf{\pi}^2=f^2 \qquad f=\text{constant}
\end{equation}

The exercise asks to show that it is possible to obtain that constraint with

\begin{equation}
\Sigma=\sigma+i\mathbf{\tau}\cdot \mathbf{\pi}=f\exp\left[i\frac{\tau\cdot \phi}{f}\right]
\end{equation}

where $\phi=(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3)$ are arbitrary functions.

The exercise is easy since it is sufficient just to take the complex transpose of $\Sigma$ and make the product:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma^\dagger=\sigma-i\mathbf{\tau}\cdot \mathbf{\pi}=f\exp\left[-i\frac{\tau\cdot \phi}{f}\right]\Longrightarrow\\ 
\Sigma^\dagger \Sigma= \sigma^2+\pi^2=f^2\exp\left[-i\frac{\tau\cdot \phi}{f}\right]\exp\left[i\frac{\tau\cdot \phi}{f}\right]=f^2\tag{5.163}
\end{equation}

My question is: there is in many notes and exercises this different parametrization of the pion fields:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma=f \exp\left[i\frac{\phi \cdot \tau}{f}\right]
\end{equation}

in such a way it is possible to obtain the same kind of Lagrangian of the previous parametrization:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{4}\text{Tr}\left[(\partial_\mu \Sigma)^\dagger(\partial^\mu \Sigma)\right]  \tag{5.164}
\end{equation}

How is it possible to relate the two parametrization? And, above all, the Lagrangian written with the trace using the first parametrization gives only the kinetic part of the pions (and the $\sigma$ fields), while the second kind of parametrization is a little more difficult to expand and I think it gives also the interaction between pions, right? 
Can someone help me to relate maybe the $\phi$ fields with the $\sigma$ and $\pi$ ones and the first parametrization with the second one?

Comment: "right?". No, you couldn't be more wrong. The constraint tells you σ is now a dependent variable, the obvious function of pions, and has to be eliminated from the "kinetic" term, yielding messy interactions. So messy, that Gursey had to reparameterize it to the exponential version you are adducing. The trivial field coordinate-change exercise is done for you in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_model).

Comment: @CosmasZachos, if I have understood your comment, you mean that in the parametrization with the σ  the Lagrangian is only kinetic but the term on σ  is defined for power series (of the pion fields) and then you have also the interaction terms; while in the parametrization with only the pions fields you have  immediately those interactions. I have also written by my own the expression using sine and cosine and I obtained what wikipedia says. However I would like to know then if the $\phi$ fields in the exercise of the Cheng - Li are physical and if they are related to the pion fields also them.

Comment: You can read up on local (no-derivatives) field redefinitions of interpolating fields in [Gasiorowicz & Geffen 1969](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.41.531), sec. II. They are magnificently non-unique: a local function of an interpolating field is an *equivalent* such of the S-matrix!

Comment: Yes, you understood me right. Both φ and π are reparameterizations for physical pion amplitudes, of course. A local field parameterization amounts to no physics when it comes to physical amplitudes, as expounded relentlessly by Schwinger and Weinberg, etc....